# Running Javascript in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, debugging

I'm loading an external .php file using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js.php"></script>
```

Within the external myfile.js.php file, I'm using:

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/javascript');
$message = "Test message";
?>
document.write('<?php echo $message; ?>');
```

Everything works fine *until* I change the name of **myfile.js.php** to just **myfile.php**

Why does it stop working if I remove the .js part from the file name? I'm serving the file as text/javascript, plus shouldn't the .js part be ignored since .php is the actual file extension?

Comment: maybe is a silly question but just to be sure, do you have renamed the src parameter to myfile.php ? like this src="myfile.php"

Comment: Yes, I'm changing both so that they correspond with each other correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, the file extension is php, "myfile.js.php" and "myfile.php" - both file extensions are "php", so that isn't the problem.

Are you definitely changing the physical file name and the src attribute - or are you just changing the physical file name and forgetting to change the script tag to...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.php"></script>
```

**UPDATE**: Having Seen The File In Action...

If you look inside of myfile.php, it has a little extra appended to the script, so it starts off well...

```
document.write('Test message');
```

But then there is a script block inside of the script file - which is being added to all files...

```
<!-- Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://..."></script>
<noscript>....</noscript>
```

It is this analytics code that causes the syntax error as these cannot be parsed by the JavaScript engine.

Comment: I'm changing both so that they correspond with each other correctly.

Comment: Do you have Firefox with Firebug installed? If so, load your page and view the "scripts" tab and check that the script is available in the drop down list (view it via the tab and check it looks correct) - also review the console tab to see if there are any specific error messages. Post any info you can and we'll find an answer for you.

Comment: I don't have access to Firefox at the moment, but when I use Developer Tools in IE8 it shows the script as being available. Plus, when I change the file name it gives me a "Syntax Error" so I know that it's trying to load the script (it's the only script on the page).

Comment: Is it anywhere we can see? Can you upload it to a test area on a website?

Comment: Also, earlier today I was able to test the page in Firefox, Opera, etc., and they all had the same problem. On different machines too. I even cleared the browser cache, flushed DNS, etc.

Comment: Was the variable $message always set to "Test message"? In the case it contains unescaped quotation marks (i.e.: ') it will lead to a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, it was always set to "Test message".

Comment: Please, do use Firefox with Firebug.

Comment: Sohnee > can I send the link to you privately?

Comment: Yes - bung it through the contact form on www.stevefenton.co.uk and I'll respond here with an answer...

Comment: Sohnee > Ahhhh, now I see! That was very observant of you to notice that! It's a good thing I only use that host for testing purposes! Thanks again!

Comment: I'm still confused as to why it works if I change the file name to myfile.js.php, especially since double file extensions don't work.

Comment: I imagine the hosting company check for the string ".js" anywhere inside of the file name and then don't append the content - so they aren't actually checking the file extension, just the presence of ".js" anywhere in the file name.

Answer (score 1):

it works fine for me (in firefox and ie) :S.. please check this:

- try displaying the myfile.php in a separate window
- Is the file been parsed as a php file?
- check the headers of the server response to see if the content-type is being sent correctly

Good luck

Comment: Tried everything and it still does the same thing.

Comment: but when you display the myfile.php does it shows "document.write('Test Message');" ??

Comment: ahh cause you're using ie i guess... i'd like to see the link if possible :) pleasedontbelong[at]gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I was unable to reproduce your problem and maybe this is not the answer, but I would suggest checking Apache configuration file **httpd.conf**. For example. search it for instances of **".js"**.
Also, there is a file named **mime.types** that associates MIME-TYPE with file extensions. Perhaps there are some errors?

Hope that will help you somehow.